# When sup norm,i.e. $\| x|| = \sup|x(t)|$ for $\forall t\in T $in C[0,1] for $T \subsetneq [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

When sup norm, i.e. $\| x||  =\sup|x(t)|$  for $\forall t\in T $in C[0,1]

$T$ is such that $T \subsetneq [0,1]$. What condition should be applied to $T$ to make  $\| x||$ a norm.

I cannot show for the property:  $\| x||=0$ iff $x=0$.

Could you please help me with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A condition is "$T$ is dense in $[0,1]$ for the usual topology". Indeed, in this case, $x(t)=0$ for each $t\in T$ implies by continuity the same for $t$ in the closure of $T$.

If $T$ is not dense in $[0,1]$, then $[0,1]\setminus \overline T$ contains a non-empty open set, hence a small interval. We then construct a continuous function which doesn't vanish on this interval, but it does outside.

Comment: some how i have difficulty understanding your answer. could you please elaborate.

Comment: What is not clear to you?

Comment: all unfortunately. first part "by continuity the same for t in the closure of T". and second: "construct a continuous function which doesn't vanish on this interval, but it does outside"

Comment: If $x$ is in the closure of $T$, approximate it by elements of $T$ and switch the limit using continuity.// If the interval is $(0,1/2)$, can you do it?